# What spells other than remove curse can cancel a Cursed Blade? Any level please, any spell caster type

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The cursed blade spell description says "any damage caused by a cursed weapon cannot be cured by ANY means until the damaged individual has received a removed curse spell (or some other effect that neutralises a curse." A creature we attacked with a cursed blade immediately healed without the cursed effect so could not cast remove curse in a players initiative turn. We thought about Contingency but this spell description describes only one spell to take affect when it is triggered. Other things happened like healing so remove curse could not be part of this contingency. I would like to know what other spells cancel cursed blade

Comment: I don't understand what these sentences in the middle mean, could you clarify? *"A creature we attacked with a cursed blade immediately healed without the cursed effect so could not cast remove curse in a players initiative turn. […] Other things happened like healing so remove curse could not be part of this contingency."*

Comment: We struck a creature with a cursed blade and hit causing damage. The damage amounted to about 200 hits but the DM said after this hit suddenly the creature was back to full hits. This happened before the creatures own initiative turn. We challenged the cursed blade such that healing could not occur without first casting remove curse but we're not told how. Spell description of cursed blade clearly says cannot be healed by ANY means until remove curse has been cast. Since the creature has not yet had the chance to act, we can't see how.

Comment: So, you are trying to establish if the GM could have legitimately bypassed the Cursed Blade in that situation, or if he is ignoring it?

Comment: So, you're not actually looking for a spell, you're asking if your DM is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The [Cursed Blade](http://dndtools.eu/spells/complete-warrior--61/cursed-blade--926/) spell is only a 4th level necromancy spell.  It's not an artifact, and there are several means by which it could be overcome.

- Cursed Blade is not [Magic Weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicWeapon.htm).  If the NPC had sufficient damage resistance, it could definitely have ignored the attack and the immediately healing could have been that effect.  (Remember that DR is per-hit, not per-round.)
- If you'd used this spell before, the NPC may have protected themselves with [Spell Immunity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spellImmunity.htm).
- The NPC may also have been by a [Globe of Invulnerabilty](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/globeOfInvulnerability.htm), possibly using metamagic or a variant spell which affects only the caster.
- the NPC may even have been in possession of some wondrous item that renders them immune to all curses in general, or this curse in particular.  (Or they could be under the protection of, or themselves be, a demigod.)

However, while there are innumerable ways for an NPC capable of casting Time Stop to avoid a paltry 4th level spell, the 200-hp of damage you mention your comments makes me suspect an alternate conclusion, which requires less of an [Exalted-Charm-Fu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/what-is-exalted-paranoia-combat) style [Xanatos Gambit](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XanatosGambit) of spellcasting and instead can be explained only by the rules in the book.  **I suspect you were fighting an illusion.**

It's hard to know for certain without having actually been there, but a key tell for, say, a [Major Image](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/majorImage.htm) is an apparent immunity to damage.  Since none of your players suggested this at the time, they obviousl believed it-- and your DM was well within the rules to take that as reason to deny you any chance to disbelieve.

Answer (score 0):

*Break enchantment* specifies that it can remove curses and is the best second choice for doing so; *wish* and *miracle* can of course do so as well but are quite excessive for the task. *Limited wish* says that it can remove the harmful effects of "many spells" but is typically listed as an option in the description of those effects. It **is** listed as an option for removing a curse via *bestow curse,* for what that's worth.

Comment: I understand, but I would expect the removal of the cursed blade effect to take effect when the creature acts in its initiative turn. This occurred including restoring full hits at the end of a players attack

Answer (score 0):

The Craft Contingent Spell feat (Complete Arcane, p. 77) allows for multiple Contingency-like effects to coexist on the same creature. A contingent *remove curse* and a contingent *heal* (or two) could work to the effects you described.

Craft Contingent Spell can be an [extremely powerful](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/lord-gareths-martini-wizard-on-a-lawn-chair) trick I suggest you don't actually use for offense, but could explain what is happening.

Another way could be becoming someway immune to the effects of a specific spell. I'm thinking *spell immunity* (but that doesn't work because "SR: no") or the enemy wielding a *Spellblade* weapon (reading the attack that the Cursed weapon deals as "targeted at him" instead of the spell being targeted at the blade, which is dubious).